# VAST tracking events

Tags: javascript, vast

I am looking into VAST advertisement and I understand the implementation except on thing, there are the tracking URI's that has to be executed, how exactly it is done with javascript, I could not find any reference about it for example below is an excerpt from a VAST XML file

```
<TrackingEvents>
          <Tracking event="midpoint"><![CDATA[http://example.com/linear-midpoint]]></Tracking>
          <Tracking event="complete"><![CDATA[http://example.com/linear-complete]]></Tracking>
          <Tracking event="start"><![CDATA[http://example.com/linear-start]]></Tracking>
          <Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[http://example.com/linear-firstQuartile]]></Tracking>
          <Tracking event="close"><![CDATA[http://example.com/linear-close]]></Tracking>
          <Tracking event="thirdQuartile"><![CDATA[http://example.com/linear-thirdQuartile]]></Tracking>
          <Tracking event="progress" offset="00:00:30.000"><![CDATA[http://example.com/linear-progress-30sec]]></Tracking>
          <Tracking event="progress" offset="60%"><![CDATA[http://example.com/linear-progress-60%]]></Tracking>
        </TrackingEvents>
```

How exactly for example this URI "http://example.com/linear-midpoint"  is executed with javascript. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The URL you are pointing to, is not available.....however maybe this be of help: https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/issues/2764

Answer (score 0):

As I tested, this tracking events is executed by player which execute VAST - as response to fired event, like AdStarted, AdStopped and so on.

Realization depends from player itself (usually create Img tag and src with tracking link).

Comment: I have done it using ajax, just open hose links via ajax,seam to work fine.